# Not able to provide default root object in load balancer cloud storage bucket backend in GCP

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, cdn

We are trying to serve a angular project from cloud storage via cloud CDN using a load balancer.
We have configured a load balancer and a cloud storage bucket backend which is pointing to static content having the build artifact of an angular project. We are able to access the angular project, by hitting the load balancer http:///index.html, which in turn redirects to angular project dashboard with route path "/dashboard".

Now, when I refresh, the output comes with an error as shown below

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code> NoSuchKey </Code>
<Message> The specified key does not exist. </Message>
</Error>
```

It seems it is looking for file name /dashboard file which is not our project.

Is there any way we can set the default root to "index.html" which will fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set angular into a proxy.  the cleanest load balancer is nginx for angular or kemp.  I could pillage someone else's work and claim it as my own like others or I just googled one of many articles  - I am not affiliated nor do I know these people.  its very simple but you may have to change resource urls from the client/server side rendering if you are calling any api's to the proxy address.

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-10-proxy-configuration-angular-json/

https://www.journaldev.com/27234/nginx-reverse-proxy-node-angular

Comment: I am able to access the static web page on http://<ip-address>. And the link turns to, <ip-address>/home. And if i refresh the web-page, the page shows XML ERROR. I suspect there is some problem with the load balancer mapping. Please see if you can find some solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web
You could use this to set the default main page and error page for your cloud storage bucket in case the error page file does not exist in the bucket, which is leading to XML ERROR.

Comment: With the above solution, I am able to bypass the error and after the refresh i am able to redirect the page to "index.html", after pointing the page to "index.html". But the status code still shows "404 not found".